# How to set Plotly JS Bars width to be automatic for normal size?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly, plotly.js

I put data into plotly bar chart and no matter what parameters I set the bar width stays like 1px.

[Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5dRL.png)

Plot config:

```
<Plot key={uniqueId}
    data={[...wrapper.data]}
    className="ea-plotly-bar-chart"
    config={{...chartConfig}}
    layout={{
        ...layoutConfig,
        width: wrapper.width,
        height: extractNumber(props.height),
        xaxis: {
            showticklabels: true,
            tickformat: props.dateFormat || '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            domain:[0,1],
            type:"date",
            autorange:true,
            ...commonAxisConfig
        },
        yaxis: {
            showticklabels: true,
            title: 'Y-axis Title',
            tickformat: 'f',
            ...commonAxisConfig
        },
        showlegend: true,
        bargap: 0.05, // Gap between bars
        bargroupgap: 0.2, // Gap between bar groups
        barmode: 'group',
        barnorm: '',
    }}
/>
```

I tried all plot bar configs and nothing worked.